# ASP.NET phone box control

Tags: .net, asp.net, controls

I'm looking for custom asp.net phone box control which contains 3 areas (!). It's something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/PhoneTextBox.aspx).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't roll your own? That's pretty simple, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the maskededit box http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

you need to use 3 maskededit boxes for this scenario